# How could you describe a straight vertical line in terms of y?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I asked my Calculus Teacher this and he had no answer, we were talking about linear equations just to brush up on grade 12 maths and I never thought to ask but is it at all possible to describe an equation like `x=3` in terms of y? There is no y term in the equation but is there any crazy math to describe it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For a vertical line, $y$ could be anything.  I suppose you could say $x=3+0y$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that does technically answer my question but I was looking for something with y = some expression.

Comment: There's no function $f(x)$ such that $y=f(x)$ describes a vertical line.

Comment: $0y=x-3{}{}{}$.

Comment: How about this? $$y=0^{-(x-3)^2}+u,\quad u\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: @Rahul:  Nice!  ${}{}{}$

Comment: @mr_e_man, what is that?

Comment: @mjw - If $x\neq3$, then we have $0$ raised to a negative power, which is undefined (or infinite). If $x=3$, then we have $0^0=1$ so $y=1+u$ which is any real number.

Comment: @mr_e_man yes! Thank you. I love this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Every equation for a line in the $xy$-plane can be put in "standard form" $Ax+By=C$.  Vertical lines in particular always can be written in the form $1x+0y=C$.  In this case it's usually nicer just to write $x=C$, but you can always interpret it as having an "invisible" $0y$ term.

Comment: But not every "standard form" describes a line.  What about $A=B=0, $and $C\ne0$?

Comment: @mjw standard form is $Ax+By=C$ for some $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ben_W, Was not contradicting your answer.  Just observed that there are choices for $\{A,B,C\}$ that do not describe a line.